# Returning desired type from Activator.CreateInstance() instead of object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.reflection

I'm trying to create an instance of specified `Type` whatever user wants to have. For a quick illustration of my purpose please see the code below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object o = GetInstance(typeof(int));
        Console.WriteLine("Created type: {0}", o.GetType().FullName);
    }

    public static object GetInstance(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of {0}", t.FullName);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
```

The problem is `Activator.CreateInstance()` returns **`object`** by default. There is also an overload of this method like `T Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` which is parameterless and returns the type you specify as `T`.

However, the problem is `T` should be hard-coded while calling this method and thus should be a fixed value. I am trying to create an instance of desired class and return it as its type.

Right now if you use this method you should write something like:

```
int i = GetInstance(typeof(int)) as int
```

I'm trying to reduce this to:

```
int i = GetInstance(typeof(int))
```

Is there a way that I can do casting inside the `GetInstance` and get rid of that `as int` repetition? By this way, my return type (and also the type I cast the object to) will be *unknown at compile time*.

Seemed impossible by design to me but I'd really appreciate if you figure it out.

**EDIT:** Where I'm stuck is e.g. while you're casting, you can do `return (T) result` if you are in a generic method, but you can't do `Type t = ...; return (t) result` this doesn't work. You cannot cast to a type which is passed to you as a parameter **which is not known at compile time**.

Comment: Don't you have the same problem with hard-coding the type in `int i = GetInstance(typeof(int)) as int`? It requires the type to be known at compile time - the same requirement as with the `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.

Comment: The customers of GetInstance method right now use `int i = GetInstance(typeof(int)) as int`, I want to make it without `as int` part, that's the whole deal actually.

Comment: I'm still having hard time understanding what's the difference between `int i = GetInstance(typeof(int))` and `int i = Activator.CreateInstance<int>()` to you? In both cases, `int` is hardcoded; in both cases, it's there twice (in the declaration and in the call).

Comment: Okay, here's the thing. `GetInstance()` is my method. I have customers. They want to use my method in their code. They are fine with `int i = GetInstance(typeof(int))`. **They don't see this as something hard coded, because it is in their code.**. They will call `GetInstance`, they won't see `Activator.CreateInstance` method. Assume you are going to fetch an object from memcached, `GetInstance` would be your method (but without a key), it will handle casting automatically and return you a type as you passed as a parameter.

Comment: Where I'm stuck is e.g. while you're casting, you can do `(T) result` if you are in a generic method, but you can't do `Type t = ...; return (t) result` this doesn't work. You cannot cast to a type which is passed to you as a parameter **which is not known at compile time**.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61460/Using-LINQ-for-type-conversion), it adds an extension method to `Type` that lets you typecast to a type passed to you as a `typeof(...)`.

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental misunderstanding of how types work.  Get ahead by casting it to (dynamic).

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan I guess it's not a good approach at all. You'd better rearchitect the whole system...you can probably use the article _dasblinkenlight_ mentioned...but I'd listen to the earlier comments and try to make your customers change their mind

Answer (score 1):

### Follow a known pattern

This is not a new problem. It is a problem facing any API that allows type-specific return values. For example, a JSON parsing library like Newtonsoft (which is, to wit, the single most popular .NET package downloaded by .NET programmers in 2019) must be able to parse a string and return a type-specific object, which may or may not be known at compile time. It might make sense to follow their example.

Newtonsoft exposes **three ways** to specify the type when deserializing. You could do as you are currently doing:

```
//Cast required
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text, typeof(MyType)) as MyType;
```

You can use a generic method:

```
//No cast required, but you have to hardcode a type as a type parameter
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(text);
```

Or you can use an instance as a template, which is great for anonymous types, although you can use it with non-anonymous classes as well. This one works via generic type inference:

```
//No cast required and no need to specify type; the type is inferred from the argument
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(text, new MyType());
```

**Here's how you'd do it:**

So for you to make this work, your code might look like this:

```
public object GetInstance(Type type)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}

int i = GetInstance(typeof(int)) as int;


public T GetInstance<T>()
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}

int i = GetInstance<int>();


public T GetInstance<T>(T template)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}

int i = GetInstance(0);
```

If you do it this way, it's hard to imagine any programmer would have trouble using your library, as the approach should already be familiar to them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could write `GetInstance` like this:

```
static T GetInstance<T>()
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

And use it:

```
int j = GetInstance<int>();
```

Comment: But the requirement is that my users should use `GetInstance(Type t)` signature. It's not for my own use, I'm offering `GetInstance` method. Assume you have 100 elements of `Type[]` instances, you can't do `foreach (var t in types){ list.add(Act.CreateInstance<t>();}` Because, a runtime value for type param `<t>` doesn't work. I'm trying to solve this.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan but what is the type of the mentioned `list`? it surely accepts `object`?? Or else if yout customers have `int i = GetInstance...` there mustn't be any difference in `int i = GetInstance(typeof(int));` and `int i = GetInstance<int>()`...as _ dasblinkenlight_ said, it's hardcoded twice...IMO the generic variant is even more readable as it has no `typeof`

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan could you at least provide some code example in which (suppose `GetInstance(typeof(T))` works) it can be used, while `GetInstance<T>()` cannot. What is the left side of the assignment supposed to be? I cannot imagine that...

Comment: Assume it is `Student s = memcached.get("student_3", typeof(Student))`. But for now memcached c# libraries mostly work like `Student s = memcached.get("student_3") as Student`. Of course my case is not memcached, but it is mostly the same. I want GetInstance signature to remain the same.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan in `Student s = memcached.get("student_3") as Student` you are having `as` operator here, don't you?

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan while all you need to do is `Student s = memcached.get<Student>("student_3")`, though it's uncleat to me, what `student_3` is here for...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to create instance of desired type:

```
public class ConcreteFactory<T>  : AbstractFactory<T>
    {
        public override T CreateInstance(string typeName,params object[] parameters)
        {
            var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            var type = assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
        }
}
```

Key here is generic type T can be used to cast the created instance, this can be used as a template to create instance of any type with parameterized constructor